# Maven dependency hell

Tags: maven, jersey, dependency-management, presto, maven-shade-plugin

I'm trying to write a new module for Presto which allows using Ranger as Authorization manager, but unfortunately I ran into some issues with dependency management.

Some dependencies are conflicting (at the moment I am stuck with Jersey) and there is no version that is suitable for all the components of the project. I tried shading it, so that multiple versions can be used together, but I didn't succeed. Here is the configuration I tried for the `maven-shade-plugin`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <dependencyReducedPomLocation>${project.build.directory}/pom.xml</dependencyReducedPomLocation>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.sun.jersey</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded.com.sun.jersey</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I also tried to exclude the dependency so that only one version is available at runtime, but this leads to a `NoClassDefFoundException`. Can anybody help me to fix this dependency hell? The full project is viewable in this repo:

https://github.com/WalkerTR/presto/tree/ranger_plugin

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: It seems like you need an [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) container like Apache Felix or Eclipse Equinox (second is not the best option), if you have to use more then one version of the same library at time, you can not fix this with build script.